# How do I verifying if site has javascript enabled and if user's browser is IE 8

Tags: javascript

How do I verify if a site has Javascript enabled and if user's browser is IE 8?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Are you saying you want to know if a particular site uses JavaScript?

Comment: You want to know on the server-side, or on the client-side?

Comment: I want to know on the client side it users browser has java script

Comment: `.net` tag deleted, as your question has nothing to do with it (nor with Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for whatever reason you need to know that you are dealing with IE8,

you have to watch for the IE9 preview, which smells like IE8,
but has some new objects:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.addEventListener) alert('IE9');
if(document.documentMode) alert('IE8'+ running as '+document.documentMode);

</script>
<[endif]-->
```

Comment: nice tip, but probably a bit over the top?

Comment: Indeed @nickf, I don't know about 'have to' :)

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional comments and some javascript code (it will work only if it's enabled, right? :))

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript"> /*do something in JS - it's enabled!*/ </script>
<[endif]-->
```

Or you may want to look at [conditional compilation in JS](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/conditionalcompile.shtml)